# Adafruit CC3000 jumper pads

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

if I solder the jumper pads on the adafruit cc3000 for use with the Arduino Mega will it still work fine with the Uno?

Comment: +1 Looks like there is a phantom down-voter doing the rounds

Comment: What specific pads are you talking about? There seem to be some on the back of the module but those seem to be there for only testing.

Comment: @seb - did this meet your need?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but is this question referring to the solder points for the ICSP pins on the full CC3000 board (not breakout)? If so then it will work fine with both, but then you're using two sets of pins for the same thing. Annoying design.

Answer (score 1):

**This module is designed to be "plug in and go"** without access to anything except the connector pads at the board edge. While there are a number of pads on the face of the board these are for "experts only" access and are unneeded for normal operation.

The only soldering required should be the addition of a 9 pin row of pins to allow the CC3000 module to be plugged into a solderless breadboard or a socket. If this is all you do then the module will work directly and interchangeably with  Arduino Uno, Leonardo/Micro & Mega. These are the only Arduino versions that a full library is available for so far. ADAFruit promise more versions will be supported "sometime".

Additional information is available from
 [WIRELESS / WIFI / ADAFRUIT HUZZAH CC3000 WIFI BREAKOUT WITH ONBOARD ANTENNA](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1469)

Solder on connector and go ...

[**Larger version of photo here** makes pin use clear - + see link above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uoaZ.jpg)

[image]

---

Example use [**weather station**](https://learn.adafruit.com/wifi-weather-station-arduino-cc3000)

[**Low power use tutorial**](https://learn.adafruit.com/low-power-wifi-datalogging)

Example use [**wireless lamp**](https://learn.adafruit.com/wireless-power-switch-with-arduino-and-the-cc3000-wifi-chip)

[**Library**](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi/cc3000-library-software)